# Allow first-time creation of data in Firebase, then restrict access

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, emberfire

I'm looking for a solution to allow first-time creation of data in Firebase and then subsequently restricting access to the owner of that data (or an administrator). Essentially, I've created a signup process for a business, which creates both a user in Firebase as well as an associated user for that business. Unfortunately, with my current schema and security rules, I'm getting `permission_denied` errors. Here's my current schema, which was generated by EmberFire using a hasMany <--> belongsTo relationship between the `business` and `employee` model:

```
+ businesses
  + business_id (generated by EmberFire)
    - name
    + employees
      - employee_id
      - employee_id
+ employees
  + employee_id (generated by Firebase's auth system)
    - first name
    - last name
    - business_id
    - role (ex: 99 for admin)
```

And here are my security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "businesses": {
      // allows only administrators of the business to read and write business data
      "$business_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/business').val() === $business_id && root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/role').val() === 99",
        ".write": "root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/business').val() === $business_id && root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/role').val() === 99"
      }
    },
    "employees": {
      // only allow employees to read/write their own data or the admin of the business they belong to
      "$employee_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $employee_id || (root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/role').val() === 99 && root.child('businesses/' + (root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/business').val()) + '/employees/' + $employee_id).exists())",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $employee_id || (root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/role').val() === 99 && root.child('businesses/' + (root.child('employees/' + auth.uid + '/business').val()) + '/employees/' + $employee_id).exists())"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone recommend an updated set of security rules/schema that would allow for data to be initially created during signup and then subsequently be only accessible to the owner/admin of that data?

*Note: I'm currently running Firebase 2.2.4 and EmberFire 1.4.4.*

Thanks in advance,
James

**UPDATE**

Here's the code used in the signup process:

```
// first, create the user account to be the admin of the business
_this.firebase.createUser({
  email: _this.get('email'),
  password: _this.get('password')
}, function(error, userData) {

  if (error) {
    flashMessages.warning(error);
  } else {

    // authenticate the user and log them in
    _this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:firebase', {
      'email': _this.get('email'),
      'password': _this.get('password')
    }).then(function() {

      // create the business record
      var business = _this.store.createRecord('business', {
        name: _this.get('businessName')
      });

      // create the employee record and associate the firebase uid
      var employee = _this.store.createRecord('employee', {
        id: userData.uid,
        firstName: _this.get('firstName'),
        lastName: _this.get('lastName'),
      });

      // add the employee<->business relationship
      business.get('employees').then(function(employees) {
        employees.addObject(employee);
      });

      // save the records to Firebase
      employee.save().then(function() {
        business.save();
      });

    }).catch(function(error) {
      flashMessages.warning(error);
    });

  }

});
```

Also, here's a snapshot of the data that illustrates what I described:

[image: Data Snapshot]

Comment: Hey James, an easy way to do *append only* is how our firechat app does it here: https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json#L11. The crux is this piece: `".write": "!data.exists()"`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That *sort of* worked. My `business` model has a name and a list of employees as mentioned above. With the addition of `!data.exists()`, it successfully creates the `business` node with `employees` but `name` is not written and I receive the following error: `update at /businesses/-JnY-AR9vTMjw9Q27BUB failed: permission_denied`. After some testing, I discovered that if I remove the `business` <--> `employee` relationship, `name` is written and I get no errors. It's almost like EmberFire is making two write requests, which would invalidate the rule? Added code above.

Comment: I see @tstirrat just commented on the related Github issue. Link for context https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your security rule requires `role = 99` but you are never setting it.

The following seems to solve your issue:

```
// create the employee record and associate the firebase uid
var employee = _this.store.createRecord('employee', {
  id: userData.uid,
  firstName: _this.get('firstName'),
  lastName: _this.get('lastName'),
  role: 99
});
```

To answer the greater question, yes the write is done in multiple parts. The `hasMany` relationships are saved individually, so as not to completely overwrite any changes that may be happening on other clients. More specifically, each `hasMany` link is added or deleted in a separate write, so there could be 2 *or more* writes.

In the case of your code, the `business/<id>/employees<employee_id>` link was saved first which meant that on the second pass - while writing the main `business/<id>` hash - the `!data.exists()` part of your rule failed. This is fine, because the employee is created and linked to the business, but the `role = 99` check also failed.

Comment: Thanks, @tstirrat! I apologize for wasting your time on something so trivial. I realized that I had removed the attribute in the model as I was toying around with things and forgot to put it back. I was so hung up on thinking that the issue was that it was being rejected because the `!data.exists()` check was failing on the second write that I didn't even bother to check the other part of the condition. Thank you again!